# HTML5 / JQuery Mobile App - AppCache/Undesired caching

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, offline-caching, html5-appcache, app-offline.htm

I've developed a JQuery Mobile app.  I am using appcache to load nothing but the main page, images, and my JQM includes.  I have * in the NETWORK section of my appcache file.  It has been working great through development until today.  Without changing any of the resources listed in my appcache file I pushed out an update, changed some styling and attributes in a few of the pages.  "Touched" my appcache file and opened the app through the icon it has on the Home Screen of my phone.  Perfect...

I rolled the styling and attribute changes through a few other pages, once again "touched" the appcache file, and pushed it out.  After opening it once again via the icon on the Home Screen it DOES NOT show the changed pages.

I opened the site in Safari on my phone and the pages are current.

I even went so far as to include the updated pages in the NETWORK section of my appcache file, still no change with the chromeless version of my web app that is loaded when I open through the icon.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: @StevenlnTN I might be possible that you would 2 time the appcache page would have resuled in error and the way appcache work if there is any error in downloading the appcache it used the old cache

Comment: Thanks Viren.  My solution has been to clear the website data on my phone when I want to make certain that I see updates immediately.  I don't think it had anything to do with the offline manifest.  Given enough time, the updated pages would come through, once they expired.